# React native: failed to load bundle unexpected super class

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Whenever I run the IOS simulator it keeps giving me this error! why is that?

```
error: bundling failed: SyntaxError: .../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob/FileReader.js: Unexpected super class type: CallExpression
  35 | const DONE = 2;
  36 | 
> 37 | class FileReader extends EventTarget(...READER_EVENTS) {
     |                          ^
  38 |   static EMPTY = EMPTY;
  39 |   static LOADING = LOADING;
  40 |   static DONE = DONE;
    at File.buildCodeFrameError
```

Comment: Images are less useful to visually impaired and search engines. You should copy and paste the error message from the console so it can be indexed for future visitors.

Comment: What version of React Native are you using? Also, have you tried to build the project in XCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faced this issue before, my `react-native` and `react-native-cli` were outdated, install `react-native-git-upgrade` and upgrade you project and it should work.

Also run the following command:

```
watchman watch-del-all &&
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* &&
rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && 
rm -rf node_modules/ && 
yarn cache clean &&
yarn install && 
yarn start -- --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by the `react-flow-props-to-prop-types` [babel plugin](https://github.com/atlassian/babel-plugin-react-flow-props-to-prop-types).

Removing it fixed it for me.

1. `yarn remove babel-plugin-react-flow-props-to-prop-types --dev`
2. Remove `react-flow-props-to-prop-types` plugin from `babel.config.js`/`.babelrc` `plugins`
3. You can also now `yarn remove prop-types prop-types-extra` if you are not using these anywhere else.
4. `react-native start` and voila! :)

Thanks to [@mattcosta7](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6236#issuecomment-393263580)